# Remove the Elements which in another string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column Airports where it has values as 'DXB,KWI,COK'.

I need to compare these column value with a string like 'DXB,LHR' remove the column value which in comma separated string?

After checking with string I want to update the column value as 'KWI,COK'.?
Any solutions

```
Airports         |id
_____________________
dxb,cok,kwi     |1
cok,dxb         |2
kwi,dxb         |3
```

Airport column id 1 will to update as 'COK,DXB' remove dxb which is in compared comma separated value?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here.  Could you illustrate your question with a before and after state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `REPLACE` function:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
  Airports varchar(256),
  id int
)

INSERT #Test(Airports,id)VALUES('dxb,cok,kwi',1)
INSERT #Test(Airports,id)VALUES('cok,dxb',2)
INSERT #Test(Airports,id)VALUES('kwi,dxb',3)
INSERT #Test(Airports,id)VALUES('kwi,dxb,zxc',4)
INSERT #Test(Airports,id)VALUES('dxb',5)
INSERT #Test(Airports,id)VALUES('aaa,bbb',6)

SELECT *,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Airports,'dxb,',''),',dxb',''),'dxb','')
FROM #Test

UPDATE #Test
SET
  Airports=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Airports,'dxb,',''),',dxb',''),'dxb','')
WHERE Airports LIKE '%dxb%'

SELECT *
FROM #Test

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

```
  SET @StartIndex = 1
  IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
  BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
  END

  WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
  BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
  END

  RETURN
```

END

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DistinctSplitString] 
(
    @string1 nvarchar(max),
    @string2 nvarchar(max),
    @chars character(1)

)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @output 
        select SP1.Item from dbo.SplitString(@string1,@chars) as SP1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.SplitString(@string2,@chars) as SP2
        ON SP1.Item = SP2.Item
        WHERE sp2.Item IS NULL
    RETURN 
END

By using this two function we can easily get values